# Excepted identifier or '(' before 'for' on dev-c++

Tags: c, function, for-loop

I use dev-c++ to write a fibonacci number generator, I use for loop to finish this task. the compiler said I got errors(Excepted identifier or '(' before 'for') in the bold statement, anyone can tell what's wrong? if you found other mistake, you can tell me too :)

Thanks for helping!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int Fib[30];
int j = 0;
int x=1;
int y=1;
int z;
int i;

**for (i = 0, i < 30, i++){**
    z = x+y;
    Fib[i] = z;
    if (j == 0){
        x=z;
        j = 1;
    }
    else if(j == 1){
        y=z;
        j = 0;
    }
}

int k;

**for (k = 0, k < 30, k++){**
    print("%d",Fib[k]);
}
```

Comment: What are those asterisks doing around your for loops?

Comment: In your line mentioned, use ";" (semicolon) instead of ","

Comment: the asterisks are an attempt to bold the lines.  bold and code dont mix though.

Comment: All this code is just floating around, without a function?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0, i < 30, i++){
```

You need to use `;` instead of `,`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
```

Comma's can be used when using more than one value, for example:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 30; i++, j++){
```

Of course, if the code above is your complete code, you'll need to add a `main()` or `other_function()`.

---

Here is the full code (I didn't check the algorithm though):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void myTest()
{
    int Fib[30];
    int j = 0;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int z;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        z = x + y;
        Fib[i] = z;
        if (j == 0) {
            x = z;
            j = 1;
        }
        else if(j == 1) {
            y = z;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
        printf("%d ",Fib[k]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    myTest();
}
```

Comment: It said [Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token after I use ; instead of ,

Comment: @freddylau1997 - you also need a `main()` or other function of course (I thought you didn't paste that in) - I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I need to put those code in function,it works now,thanks

Comment: @freddylau1997 - Yes (besides the ;), I thought you had left that out of the post. See full working code in my answer.